# IPv6 not working on any name servers. Router failing DNS test 1. Will getting new router fix?

Tags: dns, router

IPv6 not working on any name servers. Router failing DNS test 1. Will getting new router fix?

For more details: https://docs.google.com/document/d/17maFQM7ytMYSyawbapPP-_X5X4irphWKUYs9i7xsWts/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what worked was resetting the router to factory settings. I think it had a DNS virus. Presumably a new router would not have had the same issue.